# DNS Infrastructure - Delay

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns

We have a branch office in another counter, which is connected with a site-to-site VPN to our main office. The branch office does not have a local domain controller / DNS server, never the less the workstations are domain members and query the DNS server in the main office which causes a delay in name resolution while browsing the web.

Which options do i have to get rid of this delay ?

It's not possible to have a local server, but it is possible to get a online DNS service like amazon for example.

Comment: And what latency is between the clients and the DNS server, in milliseconds ?

Comment: Why is it not possible to have a local server?

Comment: @drookie it's about 250 ms (Austria - Peru)

Comment: @Daniel there is no adequate space from a server (with air conditioning etc..)

Comment: add a caching name server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it is not possible to host a server due to little space and no air conditioning.

A domain controller does close to nothing and does not need to be highly performant. If your computers don't need A/C a read-only domain controller with DNS (which I highly recommend) won't need one. And you can install that thing on a little box and now you have DNS resolution as well as site-local authentication.

Edit: You can install the DNS role without having the a ADDS/RODC role installed and you will be able to achieve your goal. However, ADDS/RODC would be only a small step to another improvement.

Comment: Why would you recommend a read-only domain controller instead of a secondary one ?

Comment: [Advantages That an RODC Can Provide to an Existing Deployment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770320%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). But that might not apply to you. I just assumed based on the information that the branch office is rather small, has no it staff, a poor WAN link and no lockable server room.

Comment: Edited the answer. You can also just install DNS on the server. But very well also install A DC/RODC if you already deploy a server.